# How to select video quality before downloading with python requests?

Tags: python, download, python-requests

When using the requests python package to download a video from a web-page is there any way to select the downloaded video quality ?

Comment: This depends on the website, if it allows to specify it in the HTTP request, you you'll be able

Comment: And if it's allowed is there a specific way to set the quality or it depends on the site?

Comment: It full depends on the website. HTTP is a protocol that explain how to pass content, headers, ... and python `requests` implement that; So that is the website that need to tell how you how to say "video in XX quality" then you'll have it in the HTTP request